# How to display just the lines above the code changes?

Tags: git, git-diff

When I do `git diff` I want to get the context lines just above (or below) the code changes, not both.

I am using `-U<n>` option for context lines.

`$git diff -U5 file1.c file1_modified.c`

Comment: I think you'll have to write your own filter. Read the context diff, which indeed includes context on both sides; write out the diff with whichever context you want suppressed, suppressed.